# org mode documentation inside emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I'm learning how to use the org-mode in Emacs, I see some hints (specifically in the babel section) that I can view this documentations from withing Emacs, how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enter Info by pressing <kbd>C-h i</kbd>, then the org-mode manual by pressing <kbd>m org</kbd> and <kbd>return</kbd>.

Comment: n.b. if you were previously viewing another info manual, you may need to type `d` before `m org` to get back to the directory listing. So: `C-h i d m org RET` (or alternatively `C-h i g (org) RET`).

Answer (score 2):

There is the manual (see the answer of ExpodingRat) but also the self help of function and key (C-h k TAB give the help of the TAB key for example.)